# How to link one model to other in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

How to create relationship in MongoDB. I have two schemas, events and bookings.

```
Events: {
 title: String,
 bookings: Array
}

Bookings; {
 title: String
}
```

In one event I have several Bookings. How can I register this?

```
mongoose.model('EventSchema', {
  title: String,
  bookings: Array
});

mongoose.model('BookingSchema', {
  title: String
});
```

So i would have:

```
Events: {
 title: 'MyEvent',
 bookings: [
  {eventone}
  {eventtwo}
  etc..
 ]
}
```

Comment: You need to use references.  You can see the documentation here:  https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So give your event schema an array of Ref to booking

```
mongoose.model('EventSchema', {
    title: String,
    bookings: [{
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'booking'
    }]
});

mongoose.model('BookingSchema', {
  title: String
});
```

then upon insert into booking take resultant _id and push onto event array

```
return EventModel
.findOneAndUpdate( query,
    {   $push: {
            bookings : currBooking_id
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott Stensland!!